# Masked strangers take baby at knifepoint

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

(This probably isn't very original and maybe is too easy, but I came up with it on my own and figured I'd post it anyway.)

Masked strangers forcibly took a baby from her mother at knifepoint.  In the process, the mother was cut and needed a blood transfusion.  The baby was terrified and screaming throughout the ordeal, but she eventually was returned to her mother and father, who didn't file charges. (Instead, the parents were charged!) Why?

Comment: That's certainly an interesting way to phrase things...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Perhaps it was

> a C-section? The "masked strangers" were the surgeons using knives and scalpels to "cut" the mother, and the baby, screaming as babies do during birth, was returned because it was the mother's own child.

Comment: I'ts pretty obvious IMO, has to be this!

Comment: If this is the correct answer, then the riddle poser must Obi Wan Kenobi. Sure, I guess that's what happened, "from a certain point of view".

Comment: Only thing here is, that the "masked strangers" here aren't taking the baby "forcibly". The mother explicitly went to them to have the baby removed.

Comment: @Nav It's forcible from the point of view that that's not how women naturally give birth -- the baby was forcibly removed from the womb, rather than being delivered via the birth canal by the mother's contractions.

Answer (score 3):

> The masked stranger can also be a vet providing care for an animal giving birth or an animal with its child